# watchman --no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code=1, signal=null, unable to talk to your watchman (Connection refused)

Tags: xcode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUVv8.png)
I am trying to run the ReactNative Project on IOS RealDevice, facing the issue while connecting to the Watchman after building the app.
Tried on the simulator.. it is working like charm. facing issues while connecting to real IOS Device on the Xcode only.

Comment: making sure only it could read/write/exec (chmod 700). or if any error showing on logs.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this issue by running `chmod 0700 '/usr/local/var/run/watchman/[yourComputerName]-state`.